# The ~/.bashrc file is missing after reboot

Tags: bashrc

In Ubuntu 14.04 each time I reboot, the `bashrc` file is missing in the `~/.` location.

What happened? Please give me some suggestions! Thanks!

**Update:**
Add new `~/.bashrc`, then `ls -l ~/.bashrc` get the output `-r--r--r-- 1`.
So `chmod 644 ~/.bashrc` get output `-rw-r--r-- 1`.Then every reboot, solved the problem that missing file. But I still need to source the file like: `. ~/.bashrc`to get every thing works.

Comment: please clarify when it happens. in the title you say, when you open a new terminal - in the question you say, when your reboot

Comment: one reason could be that some other script/process deletes it. Try to make it readonly `chmod 444 ~/.bashrc` and re-login, just to see if this works.
note: to restore the original (`rw-r--r--`) permissions use: `chmod 644 ~/.bashrc`

Comment: thx @TmTron, the missing file problem solved. but each time reboot or open a new terminal, still need to `source ~/.bashrc` to get every thing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `~/.profile` script is okay. Per default `~/.bashrc` should be loaded automatically by `~/.profile` like this:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: where is the `.profile` located? I found `/etc/profile`, and add the code you given. How do compile this script? thx

Comment: I mean the .profile in your users home-directory (I've updated the answer). Stuff in `/etc/` is for system-wide settings. 
There's no need to compile anything. It's a script and thus interpreted.

Comment: really appreciated for your help. it works. btw, change the code in `/etc/profile` works too. consider about that was system-wide. may be your choice is much better.thx.